# Concatenate Rows If Value of Another Column In Next Row Is Empty

Tags: r, concatenation

I have a data set as shown in `Input` table below. I want to combine rows `(4,5,6)`, rows `(8,9)` and rows `(11,12)` of `Input` table such that they share the same `ID` as shown in row `4,8 and 11` in the `Output` table below.

I tried `merge()`, but that didn't work as expected. The key here is the `ID` column which has unique values.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this efficiently?

**Input**

```
Row Name Val1 Val2 Unit ID
1        -0.5 5.5   V   UI-001
2    a   -0.5 2.5   V   UI-002
3    b   -0.5 5.5   V   UI-003
4    c   -0.5 5.5   V   UI-004
5    d              
6    e              
7        -45 125  Ohms  UI-005
8    f     2        kV  UI-006
9    g              
10   h   500        V   UI-007
11   i    15        kV  UI-008
12   j              
13   k                  UI-009
```

**dput() of Input**

```
structure(list(Name = c(NA, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", NA, "f", 
"g", "h", "i", "j", "k"), Val1 = c(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, NA, 
NA, -45, 2, NA, 500, 15, NA, NA), Val2 = c(5.5, 2.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
NA, NA, 125, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Unit = c("V", "V", "V", 
"V", NA, NA, "Ohms", "kV", NA, "V", "kV", NA, NA), ID = c("UI-001", 
"UI-002", "UI-003", "UI-004", NA, NA, "UI-005", "UI-006", NA, 
"UI-007", "UI-008", NA, "UI-009")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = 
c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Output**

```
Row Name Val1 Val2 Unit ID
1        -0.5 5.5   V   UI-001
2    a   -0.5 2.5   V   UI-002
3    b   -0.5 5.5   V   UI-003
4    cde -0.5 5.5   V   UI-004      
5        -45  125 Ohms  UI-005
6    fg    2        kV  UI-006  
7    h   500        V   UI-007
8    ij   15        kV  UI-008
9    k                  UI-009
```

**dput() of Output**

```
structure(list(Name = c(NA, "a", "b", "cde", NA, "fg", "h", "ij", 
"k"), Val1 = c(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -45, 2, 500, 15, NA), 
Val2 = c(5.5, 2.5, 5.5, 5.5, 125, NA, NA, NA, NA), Unit = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "Ohms", "kV", "V", "kV", NA), ID = c("UI-001", 
"UI-002", "UI-003", "UI-004", "UI-005", "UI-006", "UI-007", 
"UI-008", "UI-009")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you use `dput(your_input_df)` to provide your input table in a r-readable form? Having a hard time parsing your input provided due to all the missing values.

Comment: @MattSummersgill - I have added `dput()` values, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
out <- df[!is.na(df$ID), ]
out$Name[!is.na(out$Name)] <- tapply(df$Name, cumsum(!is.na(df$ID)), paste, collapse = "")[!is.na(out$Name)]
out
#    Name  Val1  Val2 Unit     ID
# 1  <NA>  -0.5   5.5    V UI-001
# 2     a  -0.5   2.5    V UI-002
# 3     b  -0.5   5.5    V UI-003
# 4   cde  -0.5   5.5    V UI-004
# 7  <NA> -45.0 125.0 Ohms UI-005
# 8    fg   2.0    NA   kV UI-006
# 10    h 500.0    NA    V UI-007
# 11   ij  15.0    NA   kV UI-008
# 13    k    NA    NA <NA> UI-009
```

The first line gets rid of all the rows where `ID` is `NA`. Then

```
tapply(df$Name, cumsum(!is.na(df$ID)), paste, collapse = "")
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9 
#  "NA"   "a"   "b" "cde"  "NA"  "fg"   "h"  "ij"   "k"
```

constructs the correct values for `Name` and `!is.na(out$Name)` gives us which rows of `out` should be modified (which is needed since `"NA"` isn't the same as `NA`).

Comment: .@JuliusVainora - This is a bit confusing thing about `R` to me. The data I showed as an example has empty cells. But you assumed those as `NA`. As per little `R` experience I have, they both are two different values and `is.na()` won't work when there in reality the data is empty cells. Please correct me.

Comment: .@JuliusVainora - Forgot to thank you for the solution. I will accept this as answer. Is it possible to add space with the values of the two rows I want to combine instead? Example: `f g` instead of `fg` in row `8` in column `name`.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil, I didn't assume them as `NA`, your `dput` output had them as `NA`, which a good thing to do, typically. For instance, having `""` would allow `Val1` to be numeric. If you really want `""`, which is not "empty", it's a character of length zero, you can do `df[is.na(df)] <- ""`. Sure, just replace `sep = ""` by `sep = " "`.

Comment: .@JuliusVainora - Thanks. Is it possible to add space with the values of the two rows I want to combine instead? Example: `f g` instead of `fg` in row `8` in column name.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil, yes, that's what I had in meant saying `sep = " "` instead of `sep = ""`.

Comment: It's `collapse = " "` instead of `sep`.

Answer (score 0):

Also a `dplyr` possibility:

```
df %>%
 mutate(grp = ifelse((is.na(lead(ID, default = last(ID))) & !is.na(ID)) | is.na(ID), 1, 0),
        grp = ifelse(grp != 0, cumsum(grp != lag(grp, 1, default = first(grp))), 0)) %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 mutate(Name = ifelse(grp != 0, paste(Name, collapse = ""), Name)) %>%
 filter(!is.na(ID)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)

  Name      Val1   Val2 Unit  ID    
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1 <NA>    -0.500   5.50 V     UI-001
2 a       -0.500   2.50 V     UI-002
3 b       -0.500   5.50 V     UI-003
4 cde     -0.500   5.50 V     UI-004
5 <NA>   -45.0   125.   Ohms  UI-005
6 fg       2.00   NA    kV    UI-006
7 h      500.     NA    V     UI-007
8 ij      15.0    NA    kV    UI-008
9 k       NA      NA    <NA>  UI-009
```

First, it creates a grouping variable for NA cases on "ID" and the last non-NA cases on "ID" before those NA cases. Then, it groups by that grouping variable and combines the values from "Name" into one. Finally, it filters out the cases where "ID" is NA and removes the redundant grouping variable.

Or the same using `rleid()` from `data.table` to more conveniently create the grouping variable:

```
df %>%
 mutate(grp = ifelse((is.na(lead(ID, default = last(ID))) & !is.na(ID)) | is.na(ID), 1, 0),
        grp = ifelse(grp == 1, rleid(grp), grp)) %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 mutate(Name = ifelse(grp != 0, paste(Name, collapse = ""), Name)) %>%
 filter(!is.na(ID)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)
```

Or a different possibility using `fill()`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(ID_temp = ID) %>%
 fill(ID, .direction = "down") %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Name = paste(Name, collapse = "")) %>%
 filter(!is.na(ID_temp)) %>%
 select(-ID_temp)
```

Here, you are filling the missing "ID" values with the previous non-missing value, grouping by it, and then combining the rows per groups.